# Llenar Dataset con 2 consultas diferentes

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2015, visual

tengo informacion en un servidor sql y otra informacion en un servidor Firebird. Ya tengo hecha la conexion para sql y tambien la conexion para Firebird, tambien he creado un adaptador firebird y otro para sql, ahora mi duda es, como hago para llenar un dataset con ambas consultas y mostrarlo en un dgv. Les dejo el codigo que solo muestra en el datagridview la consulta de firebird, cuando le cambio el datamember me muestra la otra, pero nunca me muestra las 2 al mismo tiempo. He leido acerca de relacionar el dataset pero lo probe y no me funciona. Desde ya les agradezco mucho si me pueden guiar con esto.

```
Private Sub buscaVentas()

        Dim consulta, consultafb As String
        consulta = "Select APELLIDOYNOMBRE as Nombre_Usuario , count(ID_USUARIO) as HORAS FROM [" + cbCampana.SelectedValue.ToString + "].DBO.VENTAS where USUARIO = '" + cbUsuario.SelectedValue.ToString + "' group by APELLIDOYNOMBRE"
        consultafb = "SELECT COUNT(UNICO) AS CONTACTOS from POSICION where VENDEDORID='" + cbUsuario.SelectedValue.ToString + "'"
        adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter(consulta, conexion)
        adaptadorfb = New FbDataAdapter(consulta, fbConexion)
        datos = New DataSet
        Principal.dgv.DataSource = datos
        adaptador.Fill(datos, "VENTAS")
        adaptadorfb.Fill(datos, "POSICION")
        Principal.dgv.DataMember = "VENTAS"
        Principal.dgv.DataMember = "POSICION"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Te comento sin ser un experto en vb.net pero creo que el dgv sólo admite un origen de datos al mismo tiempo por lo que la solución es formar una consulta que relacione campos comunes entre tu consulta sql y tu consulta firebird. Así tendrás una única query que pasar al dgv.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario. Al final pude unificar todo en la misma query con outer inner join. Saludos